# Using python, Decode client side token fetched by microsoft teams and given to tab inside teams

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, pyjwt

I am trying to learn tab SSO. When Microsoft teams fetch token from AAD and pass it to tab, I want to send that token to my application server using ajax and decode it at server end.

I can see client side token successfully decoded by manually copy pasting in jwt.ms

Is there any python code that can be used to do the same done by jwt.ms? I tried [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/issues/147#issuecomment-722379003) but getting the following error:

```
jwt.exceptions.InvalidAudienceError: Invalid audience
```

Comment: What is your audience? Parse the token to see the `aud` claim.

Comment: @CarlZhao I decoded the token manually in jwt.ms and found ```aud``` parameter, it is likes this ```api://<webapp-domain>/<client_id>``` and when i tried decoding again with the correct audience, it was successful. Thanks a lot !

Comment: In short audience is equal to the value i set in ```Application ID URI``` in ```Expose an API```. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has been resolved. This is an error caused by an invalid audience you are using. You must change it to the correct audience: `api://<webapp-domain>/<client_id>`.

This [audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso#develop-an-sso-microsoft-teams-tab) is actually the protected api that you expose in Azure.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Setting this solved my problem:

```
protectedResourceMap.set(`${my_api}`, [`${client_id}/.default`]);
```